# How to save the ListView in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)?

Tags: android, orientation

The list is pulled from a remote feed over the web, so I was trying to prevent having to reload the listview via another web pull

Basically I just want the application to save everything and then restore itself when the user changes orientation, instead of having to make another full call back data source.

when i try to change orientation from landscape to portrait and vice-versa it takes only portrait view and all my aligment in list view get disturbed. So can u suggest me what can i do ?

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    Seralize_List_Data list = new Seralize_List_Data();
    list.setList(myList);
    outState.putSerializable("key", list);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    Seralize_List_Data list= (Seralize_List_Data) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("key");
    myList=list.getList();

    SimpleAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList,
            R.layout.transactionvalues, new String[] {
                    "transaction_date_time", "user_name", "site_name",
                    "machine_name" }, new int[] { R.id.Date_Time,
                    R.id.User, R.id.Site, R.id.Machine });

    // View header =
    // (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header,null);

    lst.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```